# Stand-alone Google docs and sheets apps vs Quickoffice

Tags: google-drive, quickoffice

is the addition of the stand-alone Google docs and sheets apps an approach from Google to remove Quickoffice from the base Android build? What is different in the Stand-alone apps vs. the existing Quickoffice?

Comment: You will have to ask Google as to their reasoning for having multiple apps for the same functionality (Quickoffice Vs. Drive Vs. Docs Vs. Sheets, or Messaging Vs. Hangouts.) Any answers will be pure speculation on our part, and as such not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @Chahk Just because you don't know doesn't mean no one on the site knows. There could well be an official statement from Google, or hints from someone on the inside in a blog post or interview.

Comment: @Chank Thanks for the feedback. I'm not trying to create speculation. It is two simple stated question: 1) Is Google removing Quickoffice from Android build? 2) Difference btw Quickoffice vs. stand-alone apps. I haven't found any documentation or official statement and that is the reason why I posted the question. I made changes to the question removing my own personal opinion. Hopefully that's better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From self testing of the Drive, QuickOffice and the new Docs apps and an official Google blog posting, it seems like the strategy will be:

- Google Drive app to view and organize your files
- QuickOffice to open MS Documents
- Stand Alone Google Docs apps (Docs, Sheets, and eventually Slides) to open Google Doc Files

Some testing I did shows (Moto X 4.4.2 with Docs v1.3.144.12; QuickOffice v6.3.1.041; Drive v1.2.563.21):

- The QuickOffice app **ONLY** Opens Microsoft Format files; I am unable to load native Google Documents
- The new Docs app **ONLY** opens Google Doc Word files; I am unable to load Microsoft Format files

A [Google Blog post](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/04/new-mobile-apps-for-docs-sheets-and.html) has a statement that leads me to believe their strategy is to remove document editing from the Drive app itself, and just have it open the stand-alone apps for Google Doc files, and QuickOffice for MS document files:

> If you don’t have time now, over the next few days you’ll be prompted
>   to download the apps when you go to edit or create a document or
>   spreadsheet in your Drive app. And of course, you’ll still be able to
>   use the Drive app to view and organize all of your documents,
>   spreadsheets, presentations, photos and more.

We also may be in line for a new Google Drive update soon - which removes in-Drive editing. The iOS version of Drive has stripped in-Drive document editing (in favor of the external apps) and added a Pin Code to allow you to encrypt local documents. ([Source](http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/05/01/google-drive-ios-gets-4-digit-passcode-lock-protect-documents/))

Edit: The new Google Drive app has [been released](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/05/02/google-drive-app-updated-to-v1-3-now-requires-new-docs-and-sheets-apps-for-editing-capability-apk-download/), which removes in-Drive editing, and will prompt you to download the new Docs and Sheets apps.

Comment: you rock!! Awesome response. Everything makes sense!